# Odd linker errors, couldn't find help anywhere

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, lnk2001

```
1>client.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __Init_thread_epoch
1>client.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __Init_thread_footer
1>client.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __Init_thread_header
1>config.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
```

The project was made using v140 toolset, updated to v142 and this happened. I tried going back to old project version and building it using v140 toolset in newest VS, even tried old VS 2015 and nothing.

Comment: Please have a minimally reproducible example

Comment: Are you mixing code and pre-built libraries built with different toolsets ?

Comment: See https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=32980 which has a possible solution.